# How to send struct with array of varying length?

Tags: c, network-programming, enet

How to send struct with array of varying length? I use enet library and memcpy for serialization.

client:

```
struct data{
  enum type type;
  int* data;
};

int world[10];
for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
{
    world[i] = i;
}

struct data dt;
dt.data = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
dt.type = 1;

for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
{
    dt.data[i] = i;
}

char msg[1024];

memcpy(msg, &dt, sizeof(dt));

ENetPacket *pack = enet_packet_create(msg, sizeof(msg)+1, ENET_PACKET_FLAG_RELIABLE);
enet_peer_send(event.peer, 0, pack);
```

server:

```
ENET_EVENT_TYPE_RECEIVE:
        
            struct data copy_data;
            copy_data.data = (int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));

            memcpy(&copy_data, event.packet->data, sizeof(struct data));

            for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
            {
                printf("%d", copy_data.data[i]);
            }
```

What I made wrong? And how to send struct with array of varying length right?

Comment: For this I would probably use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), and keep both the size and the array itself inside the structure. Then you could just send all of the structure and data in it in a single "send" call.

Answer (score 2):

Turning my comment into an answer, using a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) it might be done something like this:

```
struct data
{
    enum type type;
    uint32_t length;  // Use fixed-width type since other types can be of different lengths
    int32_t data[];   // The actual array of data
};

// ...

// Create data structure
uint32_t length = 10;  // Number of elements in the array
struct data *my_data = malloc(sizeof *my_data + length * sizeof(int32_t));
my_data->type = ...;  // Set the type
my_data->length = length;  // Number of elements in the array

// Fill the array with (dummy) data
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < my_data->length; ++i)
{
    my_data->data[i] = i;
}

// ...

// Now to send the data
size_t packet_size = sizeof(my_data) + (my_data->length * sizeof my_data->data[0]);
ENetPacket *pack = enet_packet_create(my_data, packet_size, ENET_PACKET_FLAG_RELIABLE);
enet_peer_send(event.peer, 0, pack);
```

There's no copying. There's no duplication of data. There's no worrying about extra pointers. And the array inside the structure can be used like it was any other array.

---

Now for the receiving of the structure, that will be trickier because you don't really know how much data you will be receiving.

You need to receive it in *two* parts: First the main structure, using a pointer to a `struct data` and read `sizeof(struct data)` bytes; Then the actual data, reading into `my_received_data->data` and `my_received_data->length * sizeof my_received_data->data[0]` bytes.

Also be careful if you're sending between systems with different [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). You might need to do a byte-order swap of all the data on either side of the connection. Or specify that all packets are sent with a specific (network I suggest) byte order and always do a byte-order swap on both sides.